# How to modify output of certain function of File_CSV_DataSource?

Tags: php, function, pear

The following function is from a PEAR script called File_CSV_DataSource, and is a CSV parser.

CSV file is this:
name,age,skill
john,13,knows magic
tanaka,8,makes sushi
jose,5,dances salsa

The current output of this function is like this:

```
array (0 => array ('name' => 'john','age' => '13','skill' => 'knows magic',),1 =>array('name' => 'tanaka','age' => '8','skill' => 'makes sushi',),2 =>array ('name' => 'jose','age' => '5','skill' => 'dances salsa',),)
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to make the function to output like this:

```
array (array ('john','13','knows magic'), array('tanaka','8','makes sushi'), array ( 'jose','5','dances salsa'),)
```

so without the **0 =>** and without the **column header =>** , only the value of the cells

**Is there any way for me to modify the function bellow to make it output as in my example above?**

```
public function connect($columns = array())
{
    if (!$this->isSymmetric()) {
        return array();
    }
    if (!is_array($columns)) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($columns === array()) {
        $columns = $this->headers;
    }

    $ret_arr = array();

    foreach ($this->rows as $record) {
        $item_array = array();
        foreach ($record as $column => $value) {
            $header = $this->headers[$column];
            if (in_array($header, $columns)) {
                $item_array[$header] = $value;
            }
        }

        // do not append empty results
        if ($item_array !== array()) {
            array_push($ret_arr, $item_array);
        }
    }

    return $ret_arr;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built in [filegetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). It will do that for you.

Comment: The thing is that File_CSV_DataSource package has very easy to use csv manipulation but it doesn't modify the file itself, it just modifies the output. My intention is to bring some modifications (remove columns, add columns) to the csv file using this package, receive the desired output using the function above and then write to the output to the csv file using fputcsv (which requires the array in the form I specified in the question above). I don't have the experience to write a script from scratch so the easiest way would be to modify the current function to do what I need.